# How can I merge branch-based commits into another branch?

Tags: git, github

Sorry for any title-gore. I wasn't entirely sure how to phrase this question, but I can offer a deeper explanation here.

So I have 3 branches, `master` (production), `dev` (where all our most recent work is congregated), and a feature branch (a feature I've been working on for the past few weeks).

I've been rebasing `dev` into my feature branch for the past few weeks to keep up with changes, but now I'm tasked with deploying this feature directly to production (master branch) without bringing commits from the `dev` branch.

So my first thought was to interactively rebase feature branch (let's call it feature/A) into `master`, but when I try that I see 28 old commits, and none of the relevant commits that I want to rebase. There are nearly 50 commits that need to be transferred from `feature/A` to `master`.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you rebase a branch into another one, you can skip commits you did not want to be included. For easily achieving this goal you can use a tool called [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/). It allows to easily skip(or event edit) commits when doing rebase.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help if i understood your problem correctly.

let's say your **branch A** has commits with ids {`c1,c2,c3,c4`}
and you want commit `c2,c3` to merge into a different **branch B**.

Open cmd for the project and run this command  `git cherry-pick c1` and simultaneously for other commits i.e `git cherry-pick c2` so on..

Comment: I believe this would work, but would I have to do this for each commit? (there are over 50)

Comment: You can write multiple  commit ids like  `git cherry-pick c1 c2` but i think it's not a gd idea as if merge conflict occurs you may find hard to trace. I don't know any other way than these two.